# Javascript code modules mutual import [Firefox addon]

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom, jsm

I came across this strange behavior while using javascript code modules for a firefox addon. I'm not sure if this is a bug or a bad design doing mutual imports.

So let's say there are 3 modules a, b and c.

a.js

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["a"];                                                       
Components.utils.import("resource://mymodule/c.js");                                 
Components.utils.import("resource://mymodule/b.js");                                 

var a = {                                                                           
    init: function() {                                                              
        dump("A init\n");                                                           
        b.init();                                                                   
    }                                                                               
};
```

b.js

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["b"];
Components.utils.import("resource://mymodule/c.js");

var b = {
    init : function() {
        try {
            dump("B init\n");
            dump(c.foo() + "\n");
        } catch (e) {
            dump("Error C init : " + e.message + "\n");
        }
    }
};
```

c.js

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["c"];
Components.utils.import("resource://mymodule/b.js");

var c = {
    foo : function() {
        return "C Foo";
    },
};
```

a.init() is called externally. Now with the above code, I hit an undefined for 'c' from b.

```
A init
B init
Error C init : c is undefined
```

After some troubleshooting, I realized that to correct this,

- I can either swap the imports inside a.js (b is imported before c)
- Or I can remove the mutual import ( remove the import of b from within c)
  With either of these, things go fine.

In my actual code b and c represent some UI related stuff and they have mutual dependencies. I can totally get rid of a  mutual import of modules, and register a callback function for one of them. But I wish to know what is causing this behavior. As far as I understand [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.import) do not have any strict guidelines for import among modules. I am also aware that [one module when imported multiple times will be shared](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript_code_modules%2FUsing#Sharing_objects_using_code_modules) because of caching of modules. But somehow can't explain this. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a theory about what is happening, though I haven't tried running the code in a debugger to make sure:

- a.js runs and imports c.js
- c.js runs and imports b.js (before `c` is defined!)
- b.js runs and imports c.js.  But c.js does **not** run again, because it has already been imported once before.
- Since `c` is still undefined in the c.js scope (because `c.js` has not continued running yet; it is still waiting for the `import` call on line 2 to return), `c = undefined` is injected into the b.js scope.
- b.js finishes executing.
- c.js finishes executing.
- a.js finishes executing.

So b.js never receives a valid binding for `c`, and `b.init()` throws an exception when it tries to access `c.foo`.

If this theory is correct, I think you could fix the error by moving the import calls in b.js and c.js to the bottoms of those files.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like your theory is correct. If I move the imports to the bottom, c is defined. However, 2 things which I'm still not clear - also makes me wonder if this is a bug with imports.
1. MDN says, "a given module will be shared when imported multiple times. Any modifications to data, objects, or functions will be available in any scope" - I can access 'c' from 'a', before or after a b.init(). If the modules are shared, shouldn't that be available for b too ?
2. A function in 'c.js' external to 'var c' is accessible from b! Do you think variables and functions are handled separately?

Comment: The *objects* exported from a JSM are shared by all code that imports them, but *variable bindings* are not shared.

In your example, you can think of `Components.utils.import("b.js")` as a shorthand for `let b = Components.utils.import("b.js", {}).b;`.  It creates a binding called `b` in a local scope.  If `b` points to a mutable object then you can use that object to share state across modules.  But in your original test case, no object had actually been exported.

Comment: Another example: if c.js contained `let c = {foo: 1}; import("b.js"); c = {foo: 2}; import("d.js");` then b.js and d.js could end up importing different objects.  They would each be able to modify those objects, but they wouldn't see *each other's* modifications.   (c.js would be able to see both files' modifications, if it held onto a reference to each object.)

Comment: Sorry, one more example to show what I mean by "variable bindings are not shared."  If you do `import("c.js"); c.x = 1;` then you are modifying the shared object and your modification will be visible in other scopes.  But if you do `import("c.js"); c = 1;` then you are rebinding the *local* `c` variable to a different value, and this will have no effect in other scopes.

Comment: Yes, got it. But modifying variables wasn't a concern for me. Also, variable modification behavior is documented at MDN wiki.

Comment: In my test case, the reason for confusion was when I have an external function, say `cfunc()` in module `c.js` but outside variable `c`, it was accessible from `b`. The way I understand the whole thing is 1. Your explanation of order of imports 2. Function and variable symbols are handled differently - ie. function symbols are shared across all scopes with the first import, but variables have a 'stricter' import criteria, possibly as per the order of imports.
Any ways, thanks for all your inputs. I will mark this as solved.